# The best basis for approximating functions: are these statements true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a bounded interval, for example [-1,1], and $F$, the class bounded continuous functions from this interval to $\Bbb R$. Let's say we are given a function $f \in F$, and we want to approximate it with some basis functions $\{b_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$. In practice, we have to truncate the expansion. So our computational criterion of an optimal basis is having the least $L^2$ error over the interval while having the least number of terms.

1. Can I claim that the best basis functions are the orthogonal ones? If so, how can I prove it?
2. And among all orthogonal basis functions on that interval, can I claim one (e.g. orthogonal polynomials) is better than others? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Start by defining “better”

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja , "better" is the least error for fixed number of terms in the expansion. I've defined it already.

Comment: Then the answer for (1) is no. For a given orthogonal basis, there is a basis with the same number of terms which is a linear combination of the first basis, which will give exactly the same error

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja, Good point! Thanks. Didn't pay attention to it. Yet, I wonder what is the answer to (2).

Comment: For (2) I think it's yes but probably not in the way you want: consider some basis such that $f$ is in a subspace spanned by the first $n$ basis elements (extreme case: $f$ is part of the basis) -- then it's exactly representable by finitely many elements.

So you're probably more interested not in a single $f$ but rather a whole set of functions and in that case (without giving a specific description of that subspace) I think you'll have a hard time proving any basis better than another.

Comment: @subset For fixed $f$, the Schauder basis that, for all $n$, minimize $\lvert f-\sum_{j=1}^n a_jb_j\rvert_2$ are, hands down, the ones such that $f$ is linearly dependent with $b_1$. Orthogonal or otherwise. If $f$ is not meant to be fixed, then we could use a precise quantitative formulation of what $\{b_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ should minimize, as there is a quantification over $f$ and one over $n$.

Comment: @SV-97 Nice example. Thank you. You're correct. I'm interested in an entire family of functions.

Answer (score 0):

The comments answered my question, which I summarize here:

1. No. Strictly speaking, if only the $L^2$ error vs. the number of basis functions is of interest, any number of linearly-independent basis functions will do as "good" as an orthogonal basis. Although, if $f$ is known, finding the coefficient of each basis needs a projection, which indeed is simpler to compute in the case of an orthogonal basis.
2. Yes, but this requires some knowledge of the function or the family it belongs to. There's no general rule.